# Glassfish container via Cargo isn't stopped by maven when integration tests fail

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, integration-testing, cargo

I've setup Cargo to start an instance of glassfish during the pre-integration-test phase in a maven profile. My tests are then run in the integration-test phase and, finally, cargo shuts down the tomcat instance in the post-integration-test phases.

This works great when all tests pass, but if any test fails, the maven build fails, and it appears that the post-integration-test phase is never reached, which leaves the glassfish instance running (and me unable to stop it without killing the process).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make sure cargo shuts down my glassfish instance, even if the integration-test phase fails?

My maven profile:

```
<profile>
    <!-- run integration tests against the app deployed to a container -->
    <id>integration</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- override the exclusion and include integration tests -->
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>none</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>***IntegrationTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cargo.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-server</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-server</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>glassfish3x</containerId>
                        <artifactInstaller>
                            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.distributions</groupId>
                            <artifactId>glassfish</artifactId>
                            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                        </artifactInstaller>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.datasource.datasource.mysql>
                                cargo.datasource.jndi=jdbc/TrackerPool|
                                cargo.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver|
                                cargo.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/[database]|
                                cargo.datasource.transactionsupport=LOCAL_TRANSACTION|
                                cargo.datasource.username=[username]|
                                cargo.datasource.password=[password]
                            </cargo.datasource.datasource.mysql>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply based in the wrong usage of the maven-surefire-plugin which is intended for using in relation with unit test but **not** for integration tests. For such purposes the [maven-failsave-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/plugin-info.html) exist which will solve your problem.

The usage of the maven-failsave-plugin release you from defining of [include rule for integration tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes). The usual naming convention in Maven for integration tests is like this:

```
 IT*.java
 *IT.java
 *ITCase.java
```

So i would suggest to name your integration tests accordingly so you don't need any kind of exlude/include rule neither for maven-surefire-plugin (unit tests) nor for maven-failsafe-plugin (integration tests).

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The verify goal is only needed if you like to fail your build in case of failing integration tests. You have to call maven like this:

```
mvn -Pprofile clean verify
```

Comment: Oh, fantastic - that simplifies things considerably! Thanks for the help.